# Google VM instance not opening with SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are unable to connect to Google VM instance through SSH using Open in browser Window option. It is keep showing us below error screen and not moving forward.

[image: Error Screen]

Comment: Please check console messages. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> go to `Logs` section -> click on `Serial port 1 (console)`. Check if you have there any errors and update your question with this log.

Comment: In addition check https://serverfault.com/a/1003036/551540

Comment: This problem occasionally happens - try again later. As a suggestion, configure command line or GUI SSH tools on your desktop. That way SSH keys do not need to be reconfigured for the browser.

Comment: Can you show me your firewall rules?

Answer (score 1):

According to your log details, this line may point out the root cause:

```
dockerd[1356]:failed to start daemon: Unable to get the TempDir under /var/lib/docker: mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp: no space left on device
```

It means that your Compute Engine VM instance is running out of disk space.

When there's no space on the disk, there's a chance to prevent ssh service from starting.

As Compute Engine VM instances provide an increase disk size feature on the public images, you can try to do the following steps and see how it goes.

1. [increase the size of disk you're using](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd)
2. [reboot the instance or manually increase partition size](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions)