# SSH using terminal, cloud shell, or window browser in to Google Cloud VM instance not working

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am new to google cloud computing. Recently have not been able to SSH into my VM instance, previously it worked by clicking the SSH button and opened a new browser window. I have tried several fixes based on internet searches, mostly summarized below:

When I click the SSH button, it says "Transferring Keys to the VM" but never logs in and eventually times out.

Attempt 1: I attempted to follow another thread [Google VM Instance not opening with SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830501/google-vm-instance-not-opening-with-ssh) and I increased the persistent disk size and reset the VM. Now it says "Could not connect, retrying..." when I click the SSH button and eventually times out.

Attempt 2: I also tried SSHing into the VM using Google Cloud Shell using the command

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "myZONE" "VM_instance_name" --project "PROJECT_ID"
```

And got the following error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I created new keys using

```
sudo gcloud compute config-ssh
```

and it gave me this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.config-ssh) The project property is set to the empty string, which is invalid.
```

I ran the following and it seems to work

```
gcloud config set project myPROJECT_ID
Updated property [core/project].
```

But when I ran sudo gcloud again it gave me the same empty string error.

Attempt 3: I also tried setting up the log in locally using google-cloud-sdk. I followed interactive installing instructions on [Using the Google Cloud SDK installer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive). I tried obtaining ssh key using

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --project myPROJECT_ID
```

and copied in into the ssh key on for the VM thru the cloud console website. I also tried

```
sudo gcloud compute config-ssh
```

which seemed to work and gave the following

```
Updating project ssh metadata...⠼Updated [https://...].                                                 
Updating project ssh metadata...done.                                                                                                             
You should now be able to use ssh/scp with your instances.
For example, try running:

  $ ssh VMinstance.myzone.PROJECT_ID
```

When I try running the ssh command I get the following error.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname VMinstance.myzone.PROJECT_ID: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

My instance has "enable connecting to serial ports" activated.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Update: for the VM instance in question, I clicked on `serial port 1 (console)` and here are the first 100 lines

```
serialport: Connected to PROJECT_ID.Zone.VMInstance port 1 (session ID: ##..., active connections: 1).
Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google-accounts: INFO Removing user root.
Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google-accounts: INFO Removing user root from the Google sudoers group.
[1##.##8] google_accounts_daemon[822]: Removing user root from group google-sudoers
Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: Removing user root from group google-sudoers
[1##.##0] google_accounts_daemon[822]: gpasswd: /etc/group.####: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: gpasswd: /etc/group.####: No space left on device
[1##.##6] google_accounts_daemon[822]: gpasswd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: gpasswd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google-accounts: WARNING Could not update user root. Command '['gpasswd', '-d', 'root', 'google-sudoers']' returned non-zero exit status 1..
Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 200, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 285, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 318, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 681, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 437, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 372, in _get_default_tempdir#012    dirlist)#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
Jul  2 12:19:41 INSTANCE systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/ssh/sedYpckqQ: No space left on device
[1##.##1] google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/ssh/sedYpckqQ: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedeXXx0O: No space left on device
[1##.##4] google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedeXXx0O: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sed27Z7HO: No space left on device
[1##.##2] google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sed27Z7HO: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sed3bBBFO: No space left on device
[1##.##6] google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sed3bBBFO: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedUKduxP: No space left on device
[1##.##3] google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedUKduxP: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedhtixlP: No space left on device
[1##.##0] google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedhtixlP: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedy6zVAS: No space left on device
[1##.##9] google_accounts_daemon[822]: sed: couldn't flush /etc/pam.d/sedy6zVAS: No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: Restarting optional services.
[1##.##7] google_accounts_daemon[822]: Restarting optional services.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopped Regular background program processing daemon.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: Restarting SSHD
[1##.##5] google_accounts_daemon[822]: Restarting SSHD
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Instance Setup...
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: WARNING [Errno 28] No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO Running google_set_multiqueue.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/31/smp_affinity_list to 0 for device virtio1.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/31/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 0
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/32/smp_affinity_list to 0 for device virtio1.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/32/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 0
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO /usr/bin/google_set_multiqueue: line 139: echo: write error: No such file
 or directory
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO cat: /sys/class/net/ens4/queues/tx-0/xps_cpus: No such file or directory
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO Queue 0 XPS=/sys/class/net/ens4/queues/tx-0/xps_cpus for
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE instance-setup: WARNING [Errno 28] No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Started Google Compute Engine Instance Setup.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul  2 12:20:03 INSTANCE systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Instance Setup...
Jul  2 12:20:04 INSTANCE instance-setup: WARNING [Errno 28] No space left on device
Jul  2 12:20:04 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO Running google_set_multiqueue.
Jul  2 12:20:04 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/31/smp_affinity_list to 0 for device virtio1.
Jul  2 12:20:04 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/31/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 0
Jul  2 12:20:04 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO Setting /proc/irq/32/smp_affinity_list to 0 for device virtio1.
Jul  2 12:20:04 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO /proc/irq/32/smp_affinity_list: real affinity 0
Jul  2 12:20:04 INSTANCE instance-setup: INFO /usr/bin/google_set_multiqueue: line 139: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: did you change the firewall rules?

Comment: I checked the firewall settings under "Network interface details" and it is set to "Allow SSH from anywhere" for port 22.

Comment: @ark Facing same issue. Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your instance is running and you can restart it you may try logging in via serial console. This method is independed from any firewall / network settings :)

Just add a user with a password; [create a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly) like this (it will create a user and add it to `google-sudoers` group so you can do everything with this account):

```
#! /bin/bash
adduser username
echo 'sudouser:userspass' | chpasswd
usermod -aG google-sudoers sudouser
```

And then [connect to serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) you can log in. Either using console window or cloud shell: `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port instance-name`

**This will allow you to log in**. Unless there's something really wront with your VM.

But - judging from you desription - **you want regular SSH access**.

For that make sure that:

- you firewall rules don't block port 22 on this machine
- your firewall on a VM in question allows traffic on port 22
- your ethernet interface is up in the VM
- [SSH server listens](https://cplusprogrammer.wordpress.com/2016/10/17/how-to-check-if-ssh-is-running-on-linux/) (`ps aux | grep sshd`) on port 22

Then check if your VM has external IP - if not you will be only able to connect to your VM via another that has one, or via cloud shell (and of course serial console as described above).

However - since you got this `Permission denied (publickey)` message that means that for some reason your SSH keys don't work (corrupted, deleted etc). When you log in with serial console [check if they're there](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#locatesshkeys). If not [you can add them manually](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys).

----------- UPDATE ------------

Look at this line: `Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: gpasswd: /etc/group.####: No space left on device` - it says that your VM ran out of disk space. Stop your VM, try resizing your VM's disk first with gcloud compute disks resize mydiskname --size=100GB --zone=us-central1-a and start it. After the start VM's partition will be resized. –

Comment: I checked firewall settings (see comment on original question). Also checked that the VM has an external IP address. In cloud shell I followed your suggestions and created  `testuser`. When I ran the `connect-to-serial-port instance-name` command and A LOT of text prints in the window. A few lines read `...Removing user root` and `WARNING Could not update user root`. Then it cloud shell print pauses and provides a curser on a blank line but no `$`. If I hit enter, it asks me for `Instance-name login:` then password but fails to login. It randomly prints more text followed by the curser pause.

Comment: Can you paste the output of serial console after starting your instance with this startup-script ? Try using `gcloud compute --project=myproject instances get-serial-port-output myvm --zone=my_vms_zone -start=1` after you start it and paste it in your original question.

Comment: I ran `gcloud compute --project=topmed instances get-serial-port-output chs3 --zone=us-central1-a --start=1` and again A LOT of output printed on the screen. Way too much to post. The very last two lines say, `WARNING: Some serial port output was lost due to a limited buffer. The oldest byte of output returned was at offset #######9.
Specify --start=#######5 in the next get-serial-port-output invocation to get only the new output starting from here.`

Comment: Just go to your VM instances list and click on the one in question, then click on `serial port 1 (console)` and this will show all we need (hopefullly). Update your question with the last 100 lines and this should give some insight what's going on.

Comment: Updated the question as requested.

Comment: Look at this line: `Jul  2 12:19:02 INSTANCE google_accounts_daemon[822]: gpasswd: /etc/group.####: No space left on device` - it says that your VM ran out of disk space. Stop your VM, try [resizing your VM's disk first](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/resize) with `gcloud compute disks resize mydiskname --size=100GB --zone=us-central1-a` and start it. After the start VM's partition will be resized.