# Disable Google Username as Sudoer

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, ssh, sudo, sudoers

First post and new to the stack. I am working on a Google Cloud VM Instance using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. To access the VM Instance, I am using SSH via a custom port. When I complete SSH login, I show up in the shell terminal as my Google username `googleuser@vm-instance:~$`. As `googleuser`, I have full sudo privileges without having to type in a password and I'm concerned about security. If my Google account is ever compromised and hacker gains access to Google Cloud Platform, SSH would provide full sudo capabilities. How do I disable sudo privileges for `googleuser` or at minimum require a password before allowing sudo privileges after initial SSH? I still want to use SSH via custom port if possible instead of standard port 22 access.

As `googleuser` the `groups` command yields: `googleuser adm dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev lxd ubuntu google-sudoers` I assume google-sudoers is the problem?

I ran `sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers` and the only line of code in this sudoers file is this: `%google-sudoers ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Should I change `NOPASSWD:ALL` to something else? How do I set up a `google_sudoers` password before doing this to avoid being locked out? What are my other options? I have already set up a separate user in the regular sudo group that is password protected and requires Google 2FA, but my `googleuser` issue gives full access if compromised.

Comment: If your account is hacked and you have the default IAM permissions (roles) I can grant **sudo** permission easily. A simple startup script will undo what you are trying to accomplish. Simply removing the user from the sudoers group is only part of a solution. You will need to lock down your account so much, you will not be able to do anything practical with VMs. My tip: add MFA to your account so that hacking your identity will be very hard.

Answer (score 0):

**To remove a user from the groups** you can use the linux command `sudo gpasswd -d username groupname`. It works on Debian 10 straigh out of the box.

But the more important thing is that i**f your Google account get hacked then there's nothing to stop someone from accessing your VM's**. Even if you set passwords and harden your VM OS's in any way.

The only thing a attacker needs is to put a simple [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux) in your VM's metadata and restart it. It will be executed with root privilleges.

I know this 'cause I recommend this if you loose access to your VM. Even if your firewall will block everyone or the VM will be entirely without an ethernet interface - it can still be access via [interaction with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/interactive-gcloud).

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62955440/12257250) and see how easy it is.

**I recommend focusing on securing your Google Account and using 2FA to authenticate. Hardware keys would be the best solution here.**